# Why does "@PathVariable" fail to work on an interface in SpringBoot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Simple application - Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Simple interface - ThingApi.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

public interface ThingApi {

  // get a vendor
  @RequestMapping(value = "/vendor/{vendorName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  String getContact(@PathVariable String vendorName);

}
```

Simple controller - ThingController.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ThingController implements ThingApi {

  @Override
  public String getContact(String vendorName) {
    System.out.println("Got: " + vendorName);

    return "Hello " + vendorName;
  }
}
```

Run this, with your favorite SpringBoot starter-parent.
Hit it with GET /vendor/foobar
and you will see:
Hello null

Spring thinks that 'vendorName' is a query parameter!

If you replace the controller with a version that does not implement an interface and move the annotations into it like so:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ThingController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/vendor/{vendorName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getContact(@PathVariable String vendorName) {
    System.out.println("Got: " + vendorName);

      return "Hello " + vendorName;
  }
}
```

It works fine.

So is this a feature? Or a bug?

Comment: Because the `@PathVariable` in the method signature isn't inherited, you need to add it to your implementing method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just missed `@PathVariable` in your implement

```
@Override
  public String getContact(@PathVariable String vendorName) {
    System.out.println("Got: " + vendorName);

    return "Hello " + vendorName;
  }
```